# Transformar Data em String e Formatar para DD/MM/YYYY usandoTypescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Para conseguir enviar uma requisição ao servidor, preciso formatar o parâmetro 
 **dataNascimento** para que ele vá no formato DD/MM/YYYY. 
Nesse momento estou enviando ele assim :

Request URL: http://localhost:8083/api/paciente-api/?nome=Maria&dataNascimento=Wed%20Mar%2015%201995%2000%3A00%3A00%20GMT-0300%20(Hor%C3%A1rio%20Padr%C3%A3o%20de%20Bras%C3%ADlia)&size=40&page=0

O Json do filtro fica assim :

```js
{nome: Maria ,  dataNascimento: Wed Mar 15 1995 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)}
```

estou usando AngularJS com Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, utilize a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) e faça da seguinte maneira:

```
moment('Wed Mar 15 1995 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Caso queira fazer de forma manual utilize a seguinte função:

```js
function formatDate(date){
  const dateAux = new Date(date);
  
  return dateAux.getDate() + '/' + (dateAux.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dateAux.getFullYear();
}

const date = formatDate('Wed Mar 15 1995 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)')
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas caso eu não possa adicionar uma nova lib no projeto , existe outra solução ?

Comment: Opa Isaias, coloquei um exemplo sem uma lib.